# Database is not updated even after data post from Android App was successful

Tags: java, android, json

I have an android app that I am programming to post an array of data to a php file in local server. The data is in the format as bellow.
Name1->Quantity1
Name2->Qunatity2
I am trying to send it as json array but the problem is that whenever I am sending the data it shows that it is successful in posting that data. However i am not able to see any change of database that was suppose to be as a result of data that was sent form the android app. I will be thankful if someone guides or solves this problem of mine. please help me in this.

Bellow are the classes i am using to send and receive data

This is the class which is sending the data

```
public class Thirdscreen extends Activity {

    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/bootstrap-dist/postingdata.php";
    public ArrayList<QantityModelProduct> quantitymodel=new ArrayList<QantityModelProduct>();




    // Progress Dialog

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Json parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.thirdscreen);
        QantityModelProduct qmp;



        TextView showCartContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCart);
        TextView showCarttotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showtotal);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtractQuantity);

        final Controller aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        int cartSize = aController.getCart().getCartSize();

        String showString = "";
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cartSize; i++) {

            String pName = aController.getCart().getProducts(i)
                    .getProductName();
            int pPrice = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductPrice();
            int quantity = aController.getCart().getProducts(i)
                    .getProductQuantity();
            int dataProQuantityStore = aController.getCart()
                    .getProducts(i).getDatabaseProductQuantity();

            String pDisc = aController.getCart().getProducts(i)
                    .getProductDesc();

            total = total + (pPrice * quantity);
            showString += "\n\nProduct Name : " + pName + "\n" + "Price : "
                    + pPrice + "\t" + "Quantity: " + quantity + "\n"
                    + "Discription : " + pDisc + ""
                    + "\n -----------------------------------";



            //databaseQuantity-Current quantity
            int finalVal = dataProQuantityStore - quantity;
            String finalstringValue=""+finalVal;

            qmp=new QantityModelProduct(pName,finalstringValue);
            quantitymodel.add(qmp);


        }

        showCarttotal.setText("Your Total is: " + total + "Tk");

        showCartContent.setText(showString);


        final int productSize=quantitymodel.size();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Array size: "+productSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                new getQuantity().execute();

            }
        });



    }

    class getQuantity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Thirdscreen.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Processing your request..");

            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

            pDialog.setCancelable(true);

            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                    for (int i=0; i < quantitymodel.size(); i++) {
                            jsonArray.put(quantitymodel.get(i).getJSONObject());
                    }


            jsonParser.getandpostJSONFromUrl(url, "POST",jsonArray);


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            final Controller aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

            // dismiss the dialog once done

            pDialog.dismiss();
            aController.getCart().clearCart();
            aController.getProductsArraylist().clear();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "I am in second loop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FirstScreen.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }

}



public class QantityModelProduct {
    private String ProductName;
    private String ProductQuantity;

    public QantityModelProduct(String productName, String productQuantity) {

        ProductName = productName;
        ProductQuantity = productQuantity;
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONObject() {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("Name", ProductName);
            obj.put("Quantity", ProductQuantity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

}
```

The following is the Json Parser Class

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getandpostJSONFromUrl(String url, String method,JSONArray name) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(name.toString()));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpPost.setHeader("jsonArray",json.toString());
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                int response = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.e("posting Status", "Post status: " + response);
            }
            if (method == "GET") {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (method == "POST") {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer error", "Buffer error" + e);
            }

        } else if (method == "GET") {

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

and lastly the php file that is suppose to receive those datas.

```
?php
    define('DB_NAME', 'sshop');
                    define('DB_USER', 'root');
                    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
                    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');


                    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

                    if(!$link){
                    die('could not connect: '.msql_error());
                    }

                    $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

                    if(!$db_selected){
                    die('Can not  use '.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
                    }


     if (isset($_POST['jsonArray'])){ 
                        $jArray = json_decode($jsonArray,true);

                foreach ($jArray['jsonArray'] as $obj) {
                             $ProductName = $obj['Name'];   //String
                             $ProductQuantity= $obj['Quantity'];
                             $sql="Update productlist Set Quantity='$ProductQuantity' where Name='$ProductName';";
                             echo   $ProductName." ".$ProductQuantity;
                         }


                     }else {
                        echo 'empty';
                    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you get any errors on the PHP side?

Comment: No, not any @ hichris123

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not be comparing strings using ==

Try this!

```
        if (method.equals("POST"))
```

Next, to debug, see what data you are sending via the Android app to the PHP webservice, by sending the same request as response. So you know exactly if you are sending the data.

If the above step works fine, means the issue is on the PHP end. Use http://hurl.it or Postman client in Chrome to do a Post via browser, and then debug the PHP code. See if the data is being inserted.

This should solve your problem.

Nithin

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "sending the same request as response" @nithinreddy.

Comment: Means in the php code, put it in such a way that it returns whatever u send as response